# Taking out second element from Stack

Tags: scala, stack

I am learning Scala. However, on the exercise, I have some problem with Stack. How can I remove the second element from stack. I have to remove second element and put back the top element.

Thanks your advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i dont know scala but normally you would do

```
variable = pop()
pop()
push(variable)
```

save the first element, pop the second one to nirvana
and then push the first element on top again

Comment: Ah, You are right. I almost found the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Scala, but a stack is a stack.

Call `pop`on the stack and assign the returned value to a temporary variable, then pop again and push back the element you assigned with the first call tot `pop`.

Pseudo code:

```
tempVar = stack.pop();
stack.pop();
stack.push(tempVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much difference between a Stack and a List, and the Scala API documentation says this as well.

If using a List, a different approach to this is:

```
val result: (Option[T], List[T]) = myList match {
  case first :: x :: rest => (Some(x), first :: rest)
  case list => (None, list)
}
```

The explicit type on the result is for clarity. The advantage to this is you wont throw an exception if there is no second item, and it is a decent example of how to use pattern matching.

Comment: sorry, I automatically assumed you were using an immutable stack. This answer doesn't apply if you are using mutable, but I'll keep it here as an example of using an immutable stack.